# Selfie Stick - Bluetooth HID Device on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, keyboard-events, hid

I'm trying to get a "Selfie stick" to work on Windows Phone 8.1.
The Selfie stick is a HID device and is used as a keyboard, when the shutter button is pressed on the stick it sends an "Enter" keystroke to the connected device.

So far for the logic, the problem is that when I try to pair it with my phone it only stays connected for about 5-10 seconds and then disconnects.

I'm new to bluetooth coding and I read that some bluetooth profiles are not supported, is this true for HID keyboards as well?

Thanks,
Peter Larsson

Comment: Short answer, no.  "Windows Phone Store apps can access the Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice API if the manufacturer supported the HID protocol for specific devices and provided corresponding device-data to app developers. Refer to your manufacturer’s documentation for a list of supported HID devices as well as the data that you’ll need to implement device discovery." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263140.aspx

Comment: I have all the info I need to connect to the device in code but as long as the phone drops the device after 10 seconds there's not much I can do, right? "supported the HID protocol for specific device" as you state above, does the manufacturer have to explicitly specify onto which devices it will work? Sounds weird to me. //Peter

Comment: Hey Peter, have you already found a solution for your problem?
I have similar issue. The problem occurs on Lumia 720 with WP8.1 Update 1. I also tried it on my friend's Lumia 735 with WP 8.1 Update 2 (which introduces HID support) and it doesn't lose the connection. However it doesn't behave like a keyboard either (for example during text editing, pressing shutter's Enter button, doesn't call Enter on the screen).

Answer (score 1):

As it is a keyboard, simply handle keyboard events such as KeyDown and check if it is Enter. No need to deal with Bluetooth yourself.

It could be a media key (volume up) as well.

Bluetooth keyboard should stay connected. Try upgrading to Windows 10 Mobile (Fall Creators Update) where more Bluetooth APIs are available.

If it keeps disconnecting, there is not much you can do.